# How to delete .trc file using sql query

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing a performance testing, where I have created a job which captures the SQL statements each and every day. The job will save the details into trace `.trc` file automatically in one of the servers. I have created another job which runs at 6 in the evening, which will copy the information from the trace file then insert in to our necessary table using `::fn_trace_gettable`.

My question is how to delete this `.trc` file using a SQL query. I mean to clearly state that when the job running on the next day it will says this file already exists. so, i need to delete this file automatically using a sql query. I can delete it manually but I need to use SQL.

Comment: Is this Oracle or SQL-Server?

Comment: SQL Server isn't a tool to manipulate your file system - try to find another solution for this, T-SQL isn't meant to delete files ...

Comment: Implement your job via SSIS. You can call queries, services, and manipulate the file system through it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

1. You Stop Trace ; `exec sp_trace_setstatus 2, 2`
2. And Run this ; `xp_cmdshell 'del c:\delete-me-file.trc'`